# Disabling archives, search results, comments, etc?

Tags: comments, archives, seo

I am working on a site that has only text articles, and I am not making use of comments, archives, trackbacks and other features.

**How can I make so these pages show a 404 not found error?** I am not linking to those pages from my theme but it happened to me in the past that google crawled duplicated content from archives pages.

*To make it more clear, my website is just a homepage with an articles list (posts), posts don't have comments or anything, just the text.*

Answer (score 1):

Two separate parts to consider: comments / trackbacks and archive pages.

If you don't enable comments and trackbacks, no links will exist for them, thus a 404 or redirect won't be necessary. You can't link to something that isn't there :)

As for the archive pages, WP will create those whether you want them or not. If you won't want people going to them at all (which would be a bad user experience IMHO) then you can set a manual redirect for each category & tag you create to go back to the home page. However, a better bet is to set those pages to noindex / noarchive using either the SEO controls in your theme framework (if they exist) or a plugin such as [Yoast's SEO plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/).